# Tool tip for disabled check boxes in Check List Box control in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am working in an MFC windows application. I am using check boxes in Check List Box control. Some of the check boxes are disabled. How can I implement the tool tips for disabled check boxes?

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Can you implement the tooltips for enabled check boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ran Wainstein](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1715/ListBox-With-ToolTip-Support) was implemented the tool tip for each item in the list box control. This can be extended to the Check List Box control also.

**MyCheckListBox.h**

```
class CMyCheckListBox : public CCheckListBox
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyCheckListBox)

public:
  CMyCheckListBox(){};
  virtual ~CMyCheckListBox(){};
  afx_msg int OnToolHitTest(CPoint point, TOOLINFO * pTI) const;
  UINT ItemFromPoint2(CPoint pt, BOOL& bOutside) const;
  BOOL OnToolTipText( UINT id, NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult );

protected:
  virtual void PreSubclassWindow();
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

**MyCheckListBox.cpp**
           This will work only for Unicode strings.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyCheckListBox, CCheckListBox)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyCheckListBox, CCheckListBox)
  ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, 0xFFFF, OnToolTipText)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyCheckListBox::PreSubclassWindow() {
    CCheckListBox::PreSubclassWindow();
    EnableToolTips(TRUE);
}
int CMyCheckListBox::OnToolHitTest(CPoint point, TOOLINFO * pTI) const{
    int row;
    RECT cellrect;  
    BOOL tmp = FALSE;
    row  = ItemFromPoint(point,tmp);  
    if ( row == -1 ) 
        return -1;
    GetItemRect(row,&cellrect);
    pTI->rect = cellrect;
    pTI->hwnd = m_hWnd;
    pTI->uId = (UINT)((row));  
    pTI->lpszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
    return pTI->uId;
}
BOOL CMyCheckListBox::OnToolTipText( UINT id, NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult ){
    TOOLTIPTEXTW* pTTTW = (TOOLTIPTEXTW*)pNMHDR;
    CString strTipText;
    UINT nID = pNMHDR->idFrom;

    GetText( nID ,strTipText);
    lstrcpyn(pTTTW->szText, strTipText, 80);

    *pResult = 0;
  return TRUE;    
}
UINT CMyCheckListBox::ItemFromPoint2(CPoint pt, BOOL& bOutside) const{
    int nFirstIndex, nLastIndex;
    nFirstIndex = GetTopIndex();
    nLastIndex = nFirstIndex  + GetCount(); 
    bOutside = TRUE;
    CRect Rect;
    int nResult = -1;
    for (int i = nFirstIndex; nResult == -1 && i <= nLastIndex; i++){
        if (GetItemRect(i, &Rect) != LB_ERR){
            if (Rect.PtInRect(pt)){
                nResult  = i;
                bOutside = FALSE;
            }
        }   
    }
    return nResult;
}
```

Finally implement Check List Box control in the corresponding dialog box.The output is

[image]